# Delete integers in a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to get rid of the zero's in my method. Does anyone know how to do this? Do I have to convert the matrix into a string or can I just remove the elements in some way in a matrix of integers?

**From this:**

```
1 0 0 0 0

1 1 0 0 0

1 2 1 0 0

1 3 3 1 0

1 4 6 4 1
```

**To this:**

```
1

1 1

1 2 1

1 3 3 1

1 4 6 4 1
```

---

```
public static void writeElement(int[][] m){
  int[][] b = new int[m.length][m.length];
  for(int row=0; row<m.length; row++){
     b[row][0] = 1;
  }
  for(int col=1; col<m.length; col++){
     b[0][col]=0;
  }
  for(int row=1; row<m.length; row++){
     for(int col=1; col<m[row].length; col++){
        b[row][col] = (b[row-1][col-1] + b[row-1][col]);
     }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<b[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(b[i][j] + "  ");
     }
  System.out.println();
  }
}//writeElement
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want to simply not print the `0`s, or do you actually want to modify `m` to replace arrays with trailing zero elements with shorter arrays?

Comment: @rabbitguy It's not really a 2D array, it's just an array of array of int.  Not all the arrays have to be the same length.  It's perfectly legal to have something like `int[][] m = { { 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2, 3 } };`

Comment: I want to create a n*n matrix and print it without the zero's . Yes I would simply want to not print them. But since the first row of 0's are needed for the calculations of the rest of the matrix I guess I would have to get rid of them after the matrix with the zero's is created. Sorry but I'm a huge noob in java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to convert the matrix into a string

You already do, when you use System.out.println(). You just have to change what you're giving that method.

Start with what you have:

```
for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
 for(int j=0; j<b[i].length; j++){
    System.out.print(b[i][j] + "  ");//where you print results out
 }
System.out.println();
}
```

You need something a little more complex than b[i][j]+" " to get the results you want, since the default String interpretation of the integer '0' is, well, '0'. You want '0' to map to a space ' '.

The way that seems most simple to me is to make a method that handles this logic, since you may actually just want no output at all if there is a zero. Using a method lets you change this very easily later if I misinterpreted your question. (You'll have to put this method in the same class as your writeElement class.)

```
private static String getPrintValueForMatrix(int value)
{
    if(value == 0)
        return "  ";//two spaces
    else
        return value+" ";
}
```

modify your original code to call the method

```
for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<b[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(getPrintValueForMatrix(b[i][j]));//only this line changed
    }
System.out.println();
}
```

and that should give you results like this:

```
1         
1 1       
1 2 1     
1 3 3 1   
1 4 6 4 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Worked out fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java have a fixed structure. Once created, you can't dynamically remove/add slots. If you want to do that, you would have to use collection elements like java.util.arrayList.

Or, you would have to create a new array; and populate the rows differently. So instead of having always the same width; you would allocate only space for the non-zero values. Then you would iterate your whole matrix; and copy over only the non-zero values.

But of course: dealing with such a matrix will require to be very precise; as each row array might have a different length!

Option 1 (using lists) has the big advantage that you can go in and remove/add elements upon creation. Downside is: collections only work with reference types; in that case: Integer. That means a bit of memory overhead.

Option 2 requires the explicit creation of new arrays; and as said: precise dealing with lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your array `String` type, allowing you to set an element as an empty string (`""`) when you want it "deleted."  Then, when you ask for elements, you could have logic to ignore any `""`s and take only numbers.  This, of course, would mean you'd need to call `Integer.valueOf(b[/*indexOne*/][/*indexTwo*/])` to cast the entries to `int` type whenever you'd want to retrieve them.

Also, you'd need to use `String.valueOf(/*anInt*/)` in a similar fashion if you wanted to set an element with an `int`, not a `String`.